# Rafael.js reference error messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I have this animation, see: **[js fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cE26g/7/)**

When I tried to convert it notepad++ .js and .html documents, I got:

```
uncaught reference error: Raphael is not defined.
```

What should I do to fix it? I gave the reference as:

```
<script type = "text/JavaScript" src ="Raphael 2.1.0.js"> </script>
```

Comment: and you're including the raphael file in your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not including raphael.js javascript file to your document correctly.

Add code below to your .html file, right before enclosing `</body>` element and any other javascript which are doing work with raphael.js library. (In other words, all javascript in js fiddle window goes below script include tag.)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/raphael.js"></script>

// ... your raphael.js related javascript is located here ...

</body>
```

The reason why it works inside jsfiddle is that you can see from left upper corner of the page that Raphael 2.1.0 is selected, so jsfiddle includes it automatically to the page.

Hence, you should either download raphael.js file to your project folder or use extranal cdn url for the resource, such as `http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js` (but be aware, if location changes your code will stop working.)

Cheers.

Comment: Actually, I downloaded the script and then I added the reference like that <script type="text/javascript" src="Raphael 2.1.0.js"></script>. However, I could not understand what's wrong. I will try to do your suggestion. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @beginnerjs np, I saw that u had trouble with the editing question, so I corrected your stuff to visible and noticed the syntax errors. :) Glad that could help.

Comment: I am new member of stackoverflow and yes I generally had a problem while writing and editing codes properly. I am glad your correction:)